# Can i deploy ASP.NET website NOT ASP.NET Web Application on windows azure?

Tags: c#, azure

I have tried to deploy an asp.net website **NOT** asp.net web application with windows azure, so i need to know if i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

I was at a conference by Scott Guthrie one of the head developers on Azure.

He was demoing standard ASP.Net websites.

The following link tells you how to deploy a site:

[How to deploy an asp net website to windows azure](http://www.davidaiken.com/2010/07/14/how-to-deploy-an-asp-net-web-site-to-windows-azure/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you give me a link or tell me the steps are needed to do that ?

Comment: The related example referring to use windows azure with asp.net web application, and what i need that if possible to deploy asp.net website, because all articles talking about ASP.NET WEB APPLICATION NOT about ASP.NET WEBSITE

Comment: Try the second link i just added.

Comment: @astaykov Yes I know it does I realised that after, I will remove that link

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating a new Role, you required to select what type of the Role you need. Such as Web Role, WCF Web Role, Worker Role etc., That will automatically add the Role into the Cloud project. When you select an ASP.NET Web Role, you will be getting a Web Application instead of Web Site.

But once you added the role, you can extend the role with multiple Web Site, Web Application and even virtual Directories.

You can have a quick look of following url -
http://www.dotnettwitter.com/2012/03/publishing-multiple-sites-sub-sites.html
http://www.dotnettwitter.com/2012/03/publishing-multiple-sites-sub-sites_29.html